# Log method entry and exit Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging

I have used `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled` for logging the method entry and exit at run time for an application. THe logs has been saved in `/tmp/msgSends-pid.` Whre pid is process ID.
I want to save same logs while running an app on the iPhone device instead of running app on emulator using `Xcode`.
Please let me know if you require more details to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

`NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled` appears in Apple's technical note about [Mac OS X debugging magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/), but not the one about [iOS debugging magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/). It appears that it is unavailable on iOS.

Apparently, you can [log Objective-C method entries and exits using a DTrace probe in Instruments](http://kdbdallas.com/2009/02/07/log-all-accessed-methods-in-objective-c-with-dtrace/).

Comment: But dtrace hasn't been ported to iOS has it?

Comment: Nope, but you can use Instruments on iOS devices via USB or Wi-Fi.